# Change the screen resolution to 1024x768 on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen-resolution

I'm trying to download a mobile credit card app and it requires the resolution be this. How can I change my screen resolution to 1024x768 on a Samsung Galaxy S3?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Which mobile credit card app are you trying to download? From which website?

Comment: Which Android version are you running? Is the device rooted?

Comment: Ditto on Android version as per Firelord pointing out. You should always specify what Android version your are running!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to be rooted. You will need to install terminal emulator. You may also need to install some type of script management tool.

**in terminal run:**

to display current window manager settings run

```
wm size && wm density
```

**Output** ,for my device, yours will vary,

```
Physical size: 800x1280
Physical density: 180
```

[image: 1280x800]

**To set to required size** , [landscape]

```
wm size 768x1024
stop && start
```

[image: 1024x768]

**NOTE:** You WILL need to repeat the process to set your screen back to normal so, keep note of your original screen size. This is why i suggest a script management tool.

To return screen to original size; [my device, landscape]

```
wm size 800x1280
stop && start
```

You may need to reset your lockscreen wallpaper, mine doesn't seem to restore to proper size when i perform these commands.

Comment: Given that OP hasn't mentioned which Android device is installed would you mind mentioning `am display-size` as well? `wm` was introduced only in JB 4.3 and it doesn't need root access when used with `adb shell` but `am` does. But I get your point why you wrote "may need root access".

Comment: @Firelord , i assume the version running is JB as the [S3](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php) released bothe ICS and JB. As I only own KK->LP devices wm is my option. If and when the user clarifies which Android version, then they will accept the given answer or request additional information.

Comment: @Firelord , isn't it a horror that devices are still running GB? xD